Could the new picture hosting system be bringing up thumbnails?
On some questions on DIY.SE, such as this one, when clicking on the decently-sized and detailed pictures in the question:

Very tiny and un-zoomable pictures like thumbnails show, instead of big-size very-zoomable pictures:

Could there be a bug in the picture display system?
I see this in Chrome Browser Version 127.0.6533.73 (Official Build) (64-bit), but not in Microsoft Edge Version 127.0.2651.74 (Official build) (64-bit). I deleted my browsing history in Chrome including cookies and still have the issue.
My OS is Windows 10 Pro 22H2.

Please note that the "image-hosting" tag actually still has "imgur" in it, but there's no imgur hosting anymore.

This is something on your side. Perhaps some Chrome extension that mess up images.

You may be right @ShadowWizard. I just tried it on another Windows 10 PC with Chrome and the problem did not happen. Will check out the extensions differences.

@Triplefault I noticed the magnifying glass icon on the address bar. Did you zoom out while viewing another image? Chrome remembers the zoom scale for each domain.

@MetaAndrewT. Thanks, I was able to undo that zoom lock and got a bigger picture again. I still find on at least that one computer that sometimes the picture won't zoom in or out, though, even without the locked zoom or magnifying glass icon present. I'm still looking for a pattern, will report back if I find it.

There is no bug in the system. You have changed the zoom so the image will appear small.
This can be seen in the screenshot you shared:

This icon means there is a zoom-out of the page.

Thanks! I was able to undo that zoom lock and got a bigger picture again. I still find on at least that one computer that sometimes the picture won't zoom in or out, though, even without the locked zoom or magnifying glass icon present. I'm still looking for a pattern, will report back if I find it.
